# How to fix state update?

Tags: reactjs

I draw a grid *N × N*. Suppose that grid is an array of *N x N*. I need to get the array' index when I click at the element and when put it to the store.

That is, I get the coordinates *(x, y)* relative to the canvas, and translate them into the index. The store is an associative array. Recording condition: if the store hasn't index I put it, if no I delete it.

The index, which I need to be written a second time as a rule and after erasing the console give the error

*TypeError index: this.state.store.has is not a function. (The 'this.state.store.has (member)', 'this.state.store.has' is not defined)*

How to fix it?

```js
export default class SimulationField extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            store: new Map(),
            scale: 20,
            edge: this.props.edge
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(e) {
        
        let x = Math.floor(getMouseX(e, this.refs.canvas) * this.state.scale / this.state.edge)
        let y = Math.floor(getMouseY(e, this.refs.canvas) * this.state.scale / this.state.edge)
        
        let element = xy2Key(this.state.scale)([x, y])
        
        this.setState({ 
            store: ( this.state.store.has(element) )
                        ? this.state.store.delete(element)
                        : this.state.store.set(element, true)
        })
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCanvas();
    }
    
    updateCanvas() {
        const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
        renderGrid({ ctx, edge: this.state.edge, scale: this.state.scale })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas
                    ref="canvas"
                    width={this.state.edge}
                    height={this.state.edge}
                    onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                </canvas>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly, but [.delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete) won't return `store` like [.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) does.

> Returns `true` if an element in the Map object existed and has been removed, or `false` if the element does not exist.

This means that if `this.state.store.has(element)` is ever true, you are effectively just doing:

```
this.setState({ 
  store: true
})
```

Next time you try and call `store.has` you are actually just trying to call `true.has`, which doesn't work.

Try this instead.

```
if (this.state.store.has(element)) {
  this.state.store.delete(element)
} else {
  this.state.store.set(element, true)
}

this.setState({ store })
```

Comment: Upvoted as this will technically work and answers the question, but I'd like to note that `setState` works best when `state` is immutable, which `Map()` is not. While it will _technically_ work (currently), the React team has [advised against it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: There's not really a way around this if you want to keep `Map` instances in state. It's possible you want to look into using [ImmutableJS Map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) instead.